# Running soapUI tests with maven plugin

Tags: soapui, maven-plugin

I have my soapUI project in .xml. I now want to change my project as maven build so that I can integrate it as part of my daily builds. I tried to get some information on how to integrate maven and soapUI. But nothing worked.

I want to know how can I use the maven plugin in order to run my existing soap project

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the below link to start. 
It has step by step and pom.xml sample to start with it.

https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/integrations/ci-systems/maven/working.html

Hope this will help you and if you have any specific error you can post error trace here.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I now have pom.xml which has the plugin details and soap project along with couple of dependencies. My build is running successfully too. But I am seeing below messages in console

 --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webservice ---
 Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

 --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ webservice ---
 No tests to run.

What does this mean here?

Comment: This requires using the pro version so it is not the free version.

Comment: Arbind were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below plugin
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
   <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.0</version>

   <!– Change the name to identify –>
   <configuration>
      <projectFile>src/test/resources/soapui/Soapui-auto-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
      <!– Change the project file name –>
      <outputFolder>target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
      <!– Change the suite name –>
      <junitReport>true</junitReport>
      <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
      <printReport>true</printReport>
      <testFailIgnore>false</testFailIgnore>
      <projectProperties>
         <value>EnvName=${soapUiEnv}</value>
         <value>ServiceEndPoint=${ServiceEndPoint}</value>
         <value>TestReportPath=${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/</value>
      </projectProperties>
      <soapuiProperties>
         <property>
            <name>soapui.properties</name>
            <value>src/test/resources/soapui/soapui-auto_data.properties</value>
         </property>
      </soapuiProperties>
   </configuration>
</plugin>

You need to create a test suite and copy it to "src/test/resources/soapui/".
specify the path in project file tag and to execute the tests to running application run command "mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.0.0:test -DServiceEndPoint=http://localhost:8080"

You can refer below blog post, explained with example soap automation using maven plugin for spring boot application https://kodestacked.com/soap-ui-automation-using-maven-plugin-in-spring-boot/
```

Comment: Please add a code description, so other people can benefit from your answer. A only code-answer doesn't bring much and is not really meaningful